# how to call a method in class A from class B in python? i'm receiving "self is not defined"

Tags: python, class, self

i'm a python newbie. There is a python class with a method (getService) that i want to use

```
class ServicesManager
   def __init__(self, logger):
      ...initialize stuff

   def getService(self, name):
      ... do some stuff

   def anotherMethod():
      ... do more stuff
```

from another class this is how i'm calling it

```
from ServicesManager import ServicesManager
class serviceCaller:
   def __init__(self, logger):
      self.logger = logger
      self.sm = ServicesManager(self.logger)

   myService = self.sm.getService('serviceA')
```

but when i execute it i receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./serviceCaller.py", line X, in <module>
    class serviceCaller: 
  File "./serviceCaller.py", line Y, in serviceCaller
    myService = self.sm.getService('serviceA')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

what could i be doing wrong? The classes are in separated files

Answer (score 3):

myService is not in `__init__`.  It is at the class level which means that it gets executed when the class is constructed.  However, at that point, there are no instances of the class which is generally what `self` is. (after all, the class doesn't even exist yet!).

My best guess is that you wanted to do this:

```
from ServicesManager import ServicesManager
class serviceCaller:
   def __init__(self, logger):
      self.logger = logger
      self.sm = ServicesManager(self.logger)

      #Notice myService is indented under `__init__`.
      myService = self.sm.getService('serviceA')
```

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
myService = self.sm.getService('serviceA')
```

is not indented to be part of the `__init__` function, where `self` is defined.

If you meant it to be part of that function then you need to indent it.